# Magento Custom Block loads anonymously but not when declared in layout file

Tags: magento, layout, customization, block, anonymous

I just can't figure it out... This outputs the correct html:

```
file: /design/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

<?php 

    echo $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/template')
        ->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/teasers.phtml')
        ->toHtml(); 

?>
```

But if I declare the block in local.xml and use getChildHtml(), it doesn't work:

```
file: /design/default/layout/local.xml

<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <block  
            template="catalog/product/view/teasers.phtml"
            type="core/template"
            name="teasers" 
            as="teasers" 
        ></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

```
file: /design/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

<?php 
    echo $this->getChildHtml('teasers'); 
?>
```

Do I need something else??

Comment: Looks valid. Already cleared cache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question doesn't quite make sense to an experienced Magento developer.  Hopefully explaining why it doesn't make sense help you find the solution to your problem.

First, your path for `local.xml` is incorrect

```
/design/default/layout/local.xml
```

Magento's structure here is

```
app/design/frontend/package-name/theme-name/layout/local.xml
```

You're missing the package and/or theme name from your path.  That makes it hard to give you advice here  — are you sure Magento sees your `local.xml` file? (making it invalid XML and reloading looking for an error is a quick way to test this)

Secondly, you said you're using `getChildHtml` to render the block — but at the same time you're adding it to the `content` block.  The `content` block is a `test/list` block that will automatically render any block added to it.  The `content` block has no `phtml` template, therefore you can't call `getChildHtml`.  Where are you calling `getChildHtml` from?

Comment: I'm not sure why the file paths are different. I'm on a contract with this company and it's their setup. They have some module managing software and it might be using symlinks or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem.

First of all, the .phtml file was being displayed, but near the bottom of the page. Since I was calling getChildHtml near the top of the page, I never scrolled down enough to notice (big fat doh).

Secondly, I wasn't aware that you can't use getChildHtml for the content block. By trial and error I found the solution was in changing the reference from "content" to "product.info" (only 9 hours down the drain this time, not bad).

Layout file looks like this now:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block  
            template="catalog/product/view/teasers.phtml"
            type="core/template"
            name="teasers" 
            as="teasers" 
        ></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```